# Как скопировать адрес электронной почты в буфер обмена при нажатии иконки/ссылки?

Tags: email, копирование, ссылка

В блоке "контакты" вместо обычной прописи адреса электронной почты стоит ссылка href="mailto:...". При этом открывается почтовое приложение. Подскажите, какой код (html/js) позволит при нажатии этой иконки (или ссылки) не перенаправлять пользователя  почту, а просто скопировать адрес электронной почты в буфер обмена пользователя?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+%D0%B2+%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80

Answer (score 1):

в итоге, смог найти такое решение:

HTML:
`<a href="#" id="copyLink">Ссылка для копирования</a>`

JS:

```
document.getElementById("copyLink").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var variableToCopy = "Текст, который нужно скопировать";
    var tempTextArea = document.createElement("textarea");
    tempTextArea.value = variableToCopy;
    document.body.appendChild(tempTextArea);
    tempTextArea.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    document.body.removeChild(tempTextArea);
    alert("Текст скопирован в буфер обмена");
});
```